# Reverse and return Array

Tags: java, array

> Reverses an array by copying it to a new array.
>
> - Rewrite the method that reverses the array passed in the argument and returns this array.
> - Write a test program that prompts the user to.

Is this a correct solution? What could I have done better, want to learn more and get better :)

```
java.util.Scanner k = new Scanner(System.in);

   int[] numbers = new int[10];

    System.out.println("Enter "+numbers.length+" values");

    for (int i = 0;i<numbers.length;i++)
    {
        numbers[i] = k.nextInt();
    }

    int[] fixedArray = reverse(numbers);

    for (int i = 0;i<numbers.length;i++)
    {
        System.out.println(fixedArray[i]);
    }





}

public static int [] reverse(int[] a)
{
    int[] arr = new int[a.length];
    int j = a.length-1;
    for (int i =0;i<a.length;i++)
    {

        arr[i] = a[j];

        j--;


    }


    return arr;
```

Comment: _Is this a correct solution?_ Is this your question? You should provide working code or at least you should believe it's working. Someone might find a bug but finding bugs and validating algorithms isn't Code Review's primary goal.

Comment: It looks like homework? Is it homework?

Comment: @t3chb0t _"It looks like homework?"_ Is that actually relevant?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ if it wasn't we hadn't the [tag:homework] tag.

Comment: @t3chb0t Ah, THX for enlighting me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Except for the formatting (indentation, spacing, empty lines) and the missing `}` at the end, the code is correct.

In the output loop, you should count until `fixedArray.length` instead of `numbers.length`. Alternatively, you could also write:

```
for (int num : fixedArray) {
    System.out.println(num);
}
```

You should give your variables better names, especially `k` (what does it mean) and `fixedArray` (which should be `reversedNumbers`).